# Menu from jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-menu

I was using the menu function from jQuery-ui. See my [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwBNE/)

My problem is that when you mouse-over a menu and you exit, all submenu exits too. But when you are in a submenu and you leave, the submenu will stay open. it won't close until you click outside the menu

I tried to add this code but it won't work :

```
$("#menu").mouseleave( function(){
   $(".ui-menu-item").collapseAll();
});
```

I want the submenu to disappear too once I leave with the mouse

Comment: why should anyone ban you for asking the above???

Comment: it will say to me "lack of search effort"

Comment: @RolandFeghaly : If you post a question correctly, do your research and show some code (Hopefully with a fiddle), your questions will always be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will helpful for you.

Add the class `submenu` for `<ul>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".submenu").mouseout( function(){
   $(".submenu").hide();
});
$(".submenu").mouseover( function(){
   $(".submenu").show();
});
```

Demo Url : http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Uh, won't the mouseover turn on all the submenus?  Maybe you meant $(this).show/hide()?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

I found better documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/ and it seems like you want to use the `collapseAll` method on `mouseleave`. Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FwBNE/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $("ul.menu").menu();
    $(menu).mouseleave(function () {
        menu.menu('collapseAll');
    });
});​
```

**ORIGINAL:**

This seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $("div#menu > ul.menu").menu();
    menu.menu('widget').hide();
    $('div#menu').hover(function () {
        menu.menu('widget').show();
    }, function () {
        menu.menu('widget').hide();
    });
    $(menu).hover(function () {
        menu.menu('widget').show();
    }, function () {
        menu.menu('widget').hide();
    });
});​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FwBNE/4/

Comment: i appreciate ur help , but why did u hide the first menu , cant we do the same with the first menu always shown ?

Comment: i did some changes on urs , http://jsfiddle.net/GdBTc/1/  , but still have one pro , if u leave , the border will still be on menu

Comment: If you want the first menu always open, then your original fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/FwBNE/) does what you want (in Chrome, anyway). Is there a particular browser you're seeing this problem in?

Comment: try to mouse over on menu3 and mouse out , u can see that the sebmenu of menu3 will stay open , so after u leave the menu, the submenu will stay open